# PyPlot "plot()" function fails in julia 0.4.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matplotlib, julia, ubuntu-16.04

I am working with a program that is meant to take a few parameters and use a genetic algorithm to optimize a five-layer mirror coating according to said parameters. Just before termination, the program is meant to display a plot of the theoretical reflectivity of the mirror over a range of wavelengths. The last four lines of the program are:

```
plot(lam,rf)
xlabel("wavelength(AA)")
ylabel("reflectivity")
title("Broadband reflectivity")
```

When I run this from the command line (`sudo julia Broadband.jl`), the plot never displays; I put a few `println()` functions in there and there is output just before and just after `plot(lam,rf)`.

Perhaps the strangest part is the fact that I copied the entirety of the code, pasted it to the terminal and ran it directly from julia (`julia> [ENTIRETY OF .JL FILE]`), and the plot displayed. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Julia v0.4.5 is an older version, and I know there were large changes to PyCall during the v0.4.6 stage to make it compatible with v0.5-rc. Maybe it's just a version issue? Did you try pinning PyCall and PyPlot to earlier versions?

Comment: ... why `sudo` ??

Comment: without sudo, `using PyPlot` causes a segmentation fault (error 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the following from the [PyPlot README](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl#non-interactive-plotting):

> If you use PyPlot from an interactive Julia prompt, such as the Julia command-line prompt or an IJulia notebook, then plots appear immediately after a plotting function (plot etc.) is evaluated.
>
> However, if you use PyPlot from a Julia script that is run non-interactively (e.g. julia myscript.jl), then Matplotlib is executed in non-interactive mode: a plot window is not opened until you run show() (equivalent to plt.show() in the Python examples).

Thus, you must call `show()` for your plot to display when run from the command line.

Comment: Perfect! `plt[:show]()` inserted right at the end of the program worked it all out. Thank you!